# REAL datatype in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqldatatypes

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
A REAL := 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A Value is : ' || A);
END;
```

The above program ran and gave me the output as below.

```
anonymous block completed
A Value is : 123456789123456789123456789123456789123500000000000000000000000000000000
```

Can someone please explain why it is showing 0 instead of actual values after 40th digit. And also 40th digit as 5 instead of 4.

Comment: Do you have a guess?

Comment: see the docs first: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits001.htm#i287903

Comment: Have you read [the SQL Reference manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213)?

Comment: "5 instead of 4." --> rounding may help: https://www.mathsisfun.com/rounding-numbers.html

Comment: Yeah, I read that. In that they mentioned as,                                          The REAL data type is a floating-point number with a binary precision of 63, or 18 decimal.       18 decimals is the 18 digits. Why it prints all the digits i given in input?

Comment: then read again: "Can be represented to full 38-digit precision"

Comment: Well the actual good question is, why the maximal precision in NUMBER type is 38

Comment: Or the other question is "Why is it showing 40 digits of precision when the maximum precision of a `NUMBER` type is only 38?"

Comment: Thomas, Could you please explain more. I am not getting you. If it is 38 digit precision why it is showing 40 digits? And if it can store the remaining digits as 0 means why it is not storing the actual input value?

Comment: [Oracle guarantees the portability of numbers with precision of up to 20 base-100 digits, which is equivalent to 39 or 40 decimal digits depending on the position of the decimal point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref118). It's showing the 40 most significant digits; the last of those is rounded, the remaining digits are zero because you've exceeded the available precision.

Comment: Hi Alex, I agree your point. NUMBER(5,2) stores the value of 123.56, But if you gave 1256.36 it throws error. But in real datatype why it is showing the zeroes? What is the maximum precision of the REAL datatype?

Comment: Try `DECLARE A NUMBER(5,-2) := 1234567; BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( A ); END;`

Comment: @CHANDRU what do you expect that Oracle should do instead of showing  zeroes?

Comment: Instead of zeroes nothing should be displayed or it should throws error if it exceeds the precision as it is doing for other datatypes like NUMBER.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your valuable replies.

Comment: @CHANDRUS - NUMBER will only throw an error if you exceed a specified precision/scale - e.g. if you declared a variable as NUMBER(38) rather than just NUMBER.

Comment: @CHANDRU if it would show 'A Value is : 1234567891234567891234567891234567891235' (not displaying zeroes) would be wrong. An exception would not be very useful. All programming languages that I know handle this in this way.Maybe it would be more clear if it is displayed as `1.234567891234567891234567891234567891235 EE 71` or `0.1234567891234567891234567891234567891235 EE72` or `1234567891234567891234567891234567891235 EE 32` but these have the same value as `123456789123456789123456789123456789123500000000000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 0):

The [SQL language reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm) says "The REAL data type is a floating-point number with a binary precision of 63, or 18 decimal", and it's shown as FLOAT(63). And FLOAT [(p)] is:

> A subtype of the NUMBER data type having precision p. A FLOAT value is represented internally as NUMBER. The precision p can range from 1 to 126 binary digits. A FLOAT value requires from 1 to 22 bytes.

If you create a table with a REAL column is behaves like a FLOAT(63):

```
create table t42 (a real, b float(126), c float(63), d number);
insert into t42 (a, b, c, d)
values (123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456,
  123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456,
  123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456,
  123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456);

select a, b, c, d from t42;

                                                               A
----------------------------------------------------------------
                                                               B
----------------------------------------------------------------
                                                               C
----------------------------------------------------------------
                                                               D
----------------------------------------------------------------
             123456789123456789100000000000000000000000000000000 
             123456789123456789123456789123456789120000000000000 
             123456789123456789100000000000000000000000000000000 
             123456789123456789123456789123456789123000000000000
```

I've used a smaller value so it can be displayed within the SQL*Plus/SQL Developer limit of 49 digits for numformat. Notice that the FLOAT(126) and NUMBER values are not quite the same with that value.

PL/SQL is slightly different. In the standard package you can see:

```
  type NUMBER is NUMBER_BASE;
  subtype FLOAT is NUMBER; -- NUMBER(126)
  subtype REAL is FLOAT; -- FLOAT(63)
```

In a PL/SQL block your `REAL` variable can take any value that an unrestricted `NUMBER` can and has the same scale/precision effects; in this case only preserving the most significant [(38-40)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref118) digits, and rounding the rest into the least of those first 40 digits. The overall 'size' of your value, as a 72-digit number, is preserved, but you lose the precision beyond what can be stored in Oracle's internal format. If you have the same variable types as the table example and put your original values in:

```
DECLARE
  A REAL := 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789;
  B FLOAT(126) := 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789;
  c FLOAT(63) := 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789;
  D NUMBER := 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A Value is : ' || A);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('B Value is : ' || B);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('C Value is : ' || C);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('D Value is : ' || D);
END;
/

A Value is : 123456789123456789123456789123456789123500000000000000000000000000000000
B Value is : 123456789123456789123456789123456789120000000000000000000000000000000000
C Value is : 123456789123456789100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
D Value is : 123456789123456789123456789123456789123500000000000000000000000000000000
```

Notice this time that the unrestricted FLOAT and NUMBER show the same value, while the restricted FLOATs have the precision you expect.

So it is showing zeros after the 40th digit and that 40th digit is 5 instead of 4 because you've exceeded the precision and the value is being rounded to the most significant digits. The SQL REAL data type has precision of 63 binary or 18 decimal digits; but unless specified a PL/SQL REAL matches NUMBER.