# Oracle databases float types limits

Tags: oracle, floating-point

I'm not sure what is the max and min positive values I can store in oracle database for the folowing column types: FLOAT, BINARY_FLOAT and BINARY_DOUBLE.

I could not find that information in the oracle reference documentation. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Well that was easy to find - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020

Comment: Minimal positive or negative?

Answer (score 1):

I have used a following script to test the three datatypes for maximal value:

```
declare
  x  float         := 0;
  xx float         := 1;
  y  binary_float  := 0;
  yy binary_float  := 1;
  z  binary_double := 0;
  zz binary_double := 1;
begin
  <<outx>> loop loop if x+xx = x then exit outx; end if; if x+xx is not infinite then x:=x+xx; xx:=xx*2; else exit; end if; end loop; xx:=xx/2; end loop;
  <<outy>> loop loop if y+yy = y then exit outy; end if; if y+yy is not infinite then y:=y+yy; yy:=yy*2; else exit; end if; end loop; yy:=yy/2; end loop;
  <<outz>> loop loop if z+zz = z then exit outz; end if; if z+zz is not infinite then z:=z+zz; zz:=zz*2; else exit; end if; end loop; zz:=zz/2; end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('float='||x);
  dbms_output.put_line('binary_float='||y);
  dbms_output.put_line('binary_double='||z);
end;
/
```

and the results are:

```
float=9.999999999999999999999999999999999999999000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E+125
binary_float=3.40282347E+038
binary_double=1.7976931348623157E+308
```

To test for minimal positive value I have used:

```
declare
  x  float         := 1;
  xx float         := .5;
  y  binary_float  := 1;
  yy binary_float  := .5;
  z  binary_double := 1;
  zz binary_double := .5;
begin
  <<outx>> loop loop if 1-xx > 0 and x*(1-xx) = x then exit outx; end if; if 1-xx > 0 and x*(1-xx) > 0 then x:=x*(1-xx); xx:=xx*2; else exit; end if; end loop; xx:=xx/2; end loop;
  <<outy>> loop loop if 1-yy > 0 and y*(1-yy) = y then exit outy; end if; if 1-yy > 0 and y*(1-yy) > 0 then y:=y*(1-yy); yy:=yy*2; else exit; end if; end loop; yy:=yy/2; end loop;
  <<outz>> loop loop if 1-zz > 0 and z*(1-zz) = z then exit outz; end if; if 1-zz > 0 and z*(1-zz) > 0 then z:=z*(1-zz); zz:=zz*2; else exit; end if; end loop; zz:=zz/2; end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('float='||x);
  dbms_output.put_line('binary_float='||y);
  dbms_output.put_line('binary_double='||z);
end;
/
```

and the results are:

```
float=1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E-130
binary_float=1.40129846E-045
binary_double=4.9406564584124654E-324
```

Answer (score -1):

According to another post:
"While Oracle can store numbers that big (and small), it will only store a maximum of 38 significant digits.  So, the maximum value that can be stored in a NUMBER field is:

9,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999

That was the biggest number that I could put in there.  After that exponents took over."
from https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27958682/maximum-value-that-can-be-handled-by-oracle-datatype-number.html

Comment: [Sometimes you can have 40 significant (decimal) digits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34595675/266304). Which is mentioned [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref118).

Comment: Exponents are OK, they help storing bigger numbers in floating point datatypes.